# adding a key name to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects and I am using the map function to reduce that array of objects to be an array of a single element in each object. After that I am removing the dup elements in that array. After doing that I have a array like `arr = ["100", "101", "103", "104", "105"]` but I want to have a key name for each element like `arr =[{id: 100},{id: 101}, {id: 103},{id: 104},{id: 105}]`.

My initial array of objects:

```
const options = [
       { id: 1, value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
       { id: 2,value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
       { id: 3,value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
       { id: 4,value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];
```

```
let testArr = options.map(a => a.value);
let uniqueTest = [...new Set(test)];
```

So uniqueTest gives an array like `["chocolate", "strawberry", "vanilla"]`

What I want is an array with key names if that is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Take a look at [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)! You can then `map` each key to an object `{ id: key }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the desired result, you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), Which will give you a new array copy. And for changing from string to number you can use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function Which will convert the string to a number.

Kindly check the below snippet

```js
let arr = ["100", "101", "103", "104", "105"]
let output = arr.map(item => ({id: Number(item)}))
console.log(output)
```

Comment: I was attempting that but I was missing the parenthesis around the curly brackets. Thanks it solved my question.

Comment: @ShalinPatel happy to help, kindly accept if it worked for you. So it will be helpful for others on future references :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `reduce` as its not only used for getting the single desired output, it could be used to transform arrays into object key pairs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
arr = ["100", "101", "103", "104", "105"]

const newArr = (acc, cv) => {
   return {...acc, ["id"]: cv};
}

const findById = arr.reduce(newArr, {});

console.log(findById)
```

Another example

```js
const options = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'chocolate',
    label: 'Chocolate'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'strawberry',
    label: 'Strawberry'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: 'vanilla',
    label: 'Vanilla'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    value: 'vanilla',
    label: 'Vanilla'
  },
];
const newArr = (acc, cv) => {
  return { ...acc,
    [cv.label]: cv
  };
}

const findByLabel = options.reduce(newArr, {});

console.log(findByLabel)
```

https://jsbin.com/lixekodevi/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and make sure map method is returning with desired key name.

```js
const options = [
       { id: 1, value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
       { id: 2,value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
       { id: 3,value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
       { id: 4,value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];
let testArr = options.map(a => a.value);
let uniqueTest = [...new Set(testArr)];


const output = uniqueTest.map(key => ({key}));
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want :

```js
const options = [
       { id: 1, value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
       { id: 2,value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
       { id: 3,value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
       { id: 4,value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

let testArr = options.map(a => a.value);
let uniqueTest = Array.from(new Set(testArr),value=>({value}));
console.log(uniqueTest)
```